# Matlab Optimization Problem

Tags: optimization, algorithms, matlab, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to find the minimum consumption and minimum connection latency of the Bluetooth communication protocol.

I can vary 3 parameters: advertising interval, scan interval and scan window. Varying these parameters would give me the current consumption and the connection latency. My goal is to find what combination of the 3 parameters (advertising interval, scan interval and scan window) that would give me the minimum connection latency and minimum current consumption.

Right now I have a program that gives me the current consumption and connection latency corresponding to the above 3 variables. What approach should I take to find the combination of the 3 parameters that would give me the lowest current and latency values.

A more general scenario:

Let's say I have a function available to me called getLatency which takes in 3 parameters A, B and C:

result = getLatency(A, B, C)

I am trying to find the combination of A, B and C that would provide me with the lowest value returned from the getLatency() function. I am not sure how to approach this problem. Please guide me to the right approach. Let's say I do not have access to the math behind the getLatency function. All I can get is the value from getLatency based on the input parameters A, B and C.

Thank you in advance!
Any examples/algorithms would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have functional forms?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/multiobjective-optimization.html)?

Comment: Dantopa, I do not right now. What I have right now is basically an excel simulation that spits out current consumption and latency for the 3 different parameters. 

Thanks, Fabio, I will have a look at it.